# Google Cloud Storage upload images Good Practices

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, upload, google-cloud-storage

I am relatively new to Google Cloud Storage and I am wondering what's the best thing to do for me when I want to upload a User profile picture on GCS.

Should I upload my image directly from my frontend, and then update my User model with GCS URL that link to the image I uploaded ?

OR

Should I upload to my server, and then do the operation there to upload it on GCS and link it to the User Model, then delete it from my server to only keep GCS link on my User Model ?

I would say the first one since the second solution makes me loose the advantage of GCS handling the upload process, and not my server.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also agree with you here you should use first option as it give you all advantage for GCS plus it will allow uploading very large files to the server from millions of users. you can read this link to get more advantage of uploading file directly to GCS.

[Uploading images directly to Cloud Storage using Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/uploading-images-directly-to-cloud-storage-by-using-signed-url)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For testing purpose, I wanted to try @google-cloud/storage package on my React frontend, but didn't managed to make it work.

Is this package made to work on backend side only , and never on client ?

Comment: check this if it's helping https://medium.com/imersotechblog/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-gcs-from-the-browser-159810bb11e3